# Users Suggestions On Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I want to show user suggestions to the logged in user.

It should be displayed to users who the logged in user does not yet follow

i tried this but getting this error foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

```
public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user-list',[
        //    'users' => User::get(),
        //     $user = new User,
        //     'users_online'=> $user->allOnline(),

        $user_id = Auth::user()->id,

        'users' => User::whereDoesntHave('followers', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where('follower_id', $user_id);
            })->get(),
        ]);
    }
```

My Blade

```
@foreach($users as user)
    {{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: you have missed $ sign in user variable so it should be @foreach($users as $user)  and change controller return   $user_id=\auth()->id();
        return view('livewire.user-list',[
            $user_id =>$user_id ,

            'users' => User::whereDoesntHave('followers', function ($query) use ($user_id) {
                $query->where('follower_id', $user_id);
            })->get(),
        ]);

Comment: @JohnLobo put that in an answer

Comment: `[$user_id => $user_id, ...]` should be `['user_id' => $user_id, ...]`. The way you defined it, you'd have something like `$1 = 1` in that `.blade.php` view. If you use `'user_id'` instead, you'll have `$user_id = 1;` in the view. Also @dz0nika, this is a simple typo/syntax error question; those should be voted and closed appropriately, not answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `followees` relation you can use it in a `WHERE NOT IN` clause.

So; lets say you can access authenticated user's current followees (followed users by authenticated user) by calling `Auth::user()->followees`

Now we will use it to take their ids as an array and give them to `whereNotIn('id', $followee_ids)`

```
$suggestions = User::whereNotIn(
        'id', 
        Auth::user()->followees()->pluck('id')
    )->inRandomOrder()
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```